# ngRepeat printing numbers in range

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to print numbers on screen from 1 to 100, without using any kind of array or object. Instead of those, I have a variable, using like this: `$scope.number = 100;`. I found solutions for arrays, but nothing for simple numbers. I can imagine the solution for this using a for loop, but I don't know any way for using ng-repeat like that. Is there any solution or should I simple make an array of 100 elements (huh?) and loop over its elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` only works with arrays, so the closest to your requirement is to define an array of length 100 and loop over it, printing the `$index`.

```
<div ng-repeat="tmp in getArray(99) track by $index">{{::$index+1}}</div>
```

Controller/directive:

```
$scope.getArray = function(n) {
    return new Array(n);
});
```

Comment: nice solution, though, what if I had a higher number, e.x. 10000?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem, depends on available memory